# How to iterate through a property in object within an array in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, html

In AngularJs, I'm using ng-repeat option to display `questionText` property inside each object in an array.

```
[{
    "_id": "57fa2df95010362edb8ce504",
    "__v": 0,
    "answers": [],
    "options": [],
    "questionText": "what is your name?,What is your qualification?,Which city do you reside in?",
    "questionId": "H1Mb0jPA",
    "surveyId": "ryVj6Pf0"
}, {
    "_id": "57fa441e5010362edb8ce507",
    "__v": 4,
    "answers": [],
    "options": ["BE", "MBA", "MS", "MTech"],
    "questionText": "What is your degree name?",
    "questionId": "BJPQ46vC",
    "surveyId": "ryVj6Pf0"
}, {
    "_id": "57fa6fb65010362edb8ce509",
    "__v": 0,
    "answers": [],
    "options": [],
    "questionText": "Which city do you live in?",
    "questionId": "ryA2Jgd0",
    "surveyId": "ryVj6Pf0"
}, {
    "_id": "57fa70125010362edb8ce50a",
    "__v": 0,
    "answers": [],
    "options": [],
    "questionText": "Have you tried this product?",
    "questionId": "BJqGlxOR",
    "surveyId": "ryVj6Pf0"
}, {
    "_id": "57fa71085010362edb8ce50b",
    "__v": 0,
    "answers": [],
    "options": [],
    "questionText": "wassup?",
    "questionId": "H1WMbluC",
    "surveyId": "ryVj6Pf0"
}]
```

The above is the array that I'm trying to go through.

This is my HTML code for the `ng-repeat`.

```
<div ng-controller="viewQuestionController as viewQuestions">
    <div ng-repeat="questionText in viewQuestions.questions">
        <h2>{{viewQuestions.questions[0].questionText}}</h2>
    </div>
</div>
```

It just iterates through the object in the first index 5 times. How do I make it iterate through each object?
I tried `viewQuestions.questions.questionText` and `viewQuestions.questions[].questionText`
Neither of it is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

questionText property value would be displayed like the below in ng-repeat ,where questionText in ng-repeat will represent object in questions list

```
<div ng-controller="viewQuestionController as viewQuestions">
<div ng-repeat="questionText in viewQuestions.questions">
    <h2>{{questionText.questionText}}</h2>
</div>
```

You should rename the questionText in ng-repeat to like question  so  each repeated div will represent a question in questions list/array.

```
<div ng-controller="viewQuestionController as viewQuestions">
<div ng-repeat="question in viewQuestions.questions">
    <h2>{{question.questionText}}</h2>
</div>
```

ng-repeat expression -

```
ng-repeat="variable in expression"
```

where variable is the user defined loop variable and expression is a scope expression giving the collection to enumerate.
Read more here - https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Comment: Thank-you. This worked. If you don't mind, can you explain this? `<h2>{{questionText.questionText}}</h2>`

Comment: `variable in expression` – where variable is the user defined loop variable and expression is a scope expression giving the collection to enumerate.